# React Component lifecycle's methods not getting properly called as per expectation

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

Reference : http://busypeoples.github.io/post/react-component-lifecycle/

I am a newbie in React Native.

I have Navigator in main.js and I am routing 2 pages in that navigator.

While navigating to second page from first page, The cycle methods from componentWillReceiveProps() to componentDidUpdate() gets called for the first page.

It should not get call as there is no props on the first page is changing. Even render() method for the first page is getting called. I just want to simply go to second page.

Comment: It's going to be very hard for us to help you without looking at your code.

Comment: I ran into similar issues with RN.  I didn't dig into the internals to see how navigator works, but basically concluded that changing routes is not the same as changing pages on the web and the components don't get unmounted as you might expect.

Comment: even if props are not changing, react can re-render component unless you add `shouldComponentUpdate` check

Comment: @ken4z yeah, Even I think the same, changing routes is not the same but there is no proper explanation anywhere.

Comment: @Deadfish yeah i know,returning false from shouldComponentUpdate() saves the below cycle and re-rendering of the current component. One should check whether the props or the state is changed or not and accordingly return a boolean from shouldComponentUpdate()  for better performance.